# How to fix the build issue : Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name=xxx </macro>

Tags: android, gradle

I am building an Android app projec using gradle in Android Studio.  I was success before I add an sdk via implementation in build.gradle. But When I  add it in build.gradle file
(implementation 'com.xxxx..xx:test_sdk:1.1.5' ) , do "sync now" and then run build ( ./gradlew assembleRelease ).  It failed,  like this:

> Task :sdk_test_main:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
> ERROR:/home/hamm/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a0305bf407e6b15092bb9bee2c92826c/material-1.8.0/res/values/values.xml: Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'

If I remove this, it will build successful.
How to fix it?  I am not aware of if it is caused by duplicated resource in other sdks?
Thanks

Comment: Where is the resource in question found? Can you share it's XML?

Comment: It seems the auto generated file: 
: /home/hamm/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a0305bf407e6b15092bb9bee2c92826c/material-1.8.0/res/values/values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

Them contents are: 
     <item name="shapeAppearance">@macro/m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape</item>

Comment: Thanks.  This problem is resolved. The root cause is that:  this sdk dependancy google material has conflict with  other module.  So the solution is like this:

implementation ('com.xx.upf:upf-sdk:1.1.5-22101') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.material'
    }